# Performing a "Transaction" in ElasticSerch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Let's suppose I have a million objects I need to save to ElasticSearch. One of the requirements of saving the objects, is it can only be searched after all the items have been saved -- otherwise the results (which has to do with Counts and Sums of different properties of the saved objects -- think Financial calculations) will be wrong.

Here is the code I currently have to save the objects:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
ACTIONS = []
for item in HISTORY_DATA.values():
    ACTIONS.append({
        "_index": ES_INDEX_NAME,
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": item.pop('_id'),
        "_source": item
    })
_ = helpers.bulk(self.es, ACTIONS)
```

How would I save 20k objects at a time, but 'commit' the transaction only after all the items have been saved? Or, if I have to save 'all of them at once', how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch doesn't have transactions only single documents actions are atomic.

If your elasticsearch index should be usable only after all items are inserted you can use this approach:

1. Configure your application to use *index alias*.
   *(at this point alias doesn't point to anything - it's OK)*
2. Create an index (e.g., `index_1`) and use bulk insert to add all documents.
   *(index is ready to use)*
3. Point your *index alias* to `index_1`.
   *(your application can use `index_1`)*
4. If you need to add new batch of items create new index `index_2`, insert all old and new documents to it. Perform any needed validations to make sure everything is OK.
   *(changes to this index are invisible to your application)*
5. Point your *index alias* to `index_2`.
   *(this works like committing transaction and switching to old index is like transaction rollback)*
6. Remove `index_1`.

Repeat points 4,5,6 any time you need to add new set of documents. I use this approach on several sites each having from 10k to 50k documents added to index with each update.

Comment: Is it possible to repeat 4,5,6 dynamically? Since the next time you cannot create a new index `index_2` because it already exists? Or you create `index_3`?

Comment: We have used `index_currenttimestap` as naming scheme.

Comment: Thanks for replying. One more question:  How do you update the index name when querying the index. Changing  it manually it doesn't seam like a neat solution. Did you use the asterisk `index_name-*`  or you have a neater solution?

Comment: Also, since you are using timestamps how you keep track of the previous index name? Since you have to perform step 6 (removing it)?

Comment: Just get a list of indexes in sorted order, the first one will be the oldest. I'm not sure what do you mean in the first question. Application only uses an alias for all queries so it doesn't have to know the current index name.

Comment: Yes, I realized that I just need to know the alias name which is constant all the time. However, for removing I just deleted all the indices with index_name-* except the new one I just created.

Answer (score 1):

No such thing as a transaction in Elasticsearch.

For more info, see here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/concurrency-solutions.html

Specifically:

> > The problem is that Elasticsearch does not support ACID transactions. Changes to individual documents are ACIDic, but not changes involving multiple documents.

Comment: how would you then accomplish the above of only allowing someone to search those results after it's been saved? Certainly, I'm not the first person to try to accomplish this behavior...

Comment: You could probably have some sort of marker field on them, let's say `"hidden": "some_random_hash_generated_for_the_batch"`, then do an update-by-query to un-hide all of the documents matching that hash.

Comment: @AKX thanks, I'm going to use that approach. How would I then do the following in ES? Perhaps this should be a separate question: `UPDATE myESIndex SET is_hidden = False WHERE transaction_guid='XXX'`