# Transaction with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, transactions

Im trying to find the best way to commit a transactional batch of documents. The batch will include an updates and additions of new documents to an index. 
I want this batch to have a transaction like properties that will make all documents visible for search only after i have verified the batch have been fully committed.

Also would like an option to roll back if something went wrong.

What I got until now is... Ill clone the target index using re-index. Commit my batch there. Verify that everything is done.
And then ill add and alias to this index making it searchable .. all queries will use the alias only .. 
And the same alias will be removed from the original index

I feel like there shuld be a simpler approach to this .. hope you can help

Comment: The approach you describe is the one that's been accepted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52281678/performing-a-transaction-in-elasticserch/52284050#52284050) and which makes the most sense, since transaction are not (and will probably never be) supported in ES.